# The array 0 value won't generate nor exist

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a game similar to wordle. The problem I'm having is that while I try to compare the value of word[0] with guess[0], but it always prints a null value. The alphabet is made to avoid k j w x y. Don't mind the italian texts

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    int i, j, err, check;
    char guess[8], word[8];
    char alpha[21] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','z'};
   
    srand(time(0));
   
   
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        word[i] = alpha[rand() % 21];
    }
   
   
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        printf("%c", word[i]);
    }
    
    
    do
    {
        printf("\nProva ad indovinare la parola: ");
        scanf(" %8s", guess);
        err=0;
        check=0;

        for(i=0; i<8; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<21; j++)
            {
                if (guess[i]==alpha[j])
                    break;
            }
            if (j==21){
                err = 1;
                break;
        }
    }
     
    if (err==1)
        printf("Puoi inserire solo lettere comprese nellalfabeto italiano e devono per forza essere 8 lettere\n");

    }while(err==1);
    
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        printf("%c", guess[i]);
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<8;i++){
        check=0;
        if (guess[i]==word[i]){
            printf("\033[0;32m");//green
            printf("%c", guess[i]);
            check=1;
        }
        for(j=0;j<8;j++){
            if (check==1)
                break;
            else if (guess[i]==word[j]){
                printf("\033[0;33m");//yellow
                printf("%c", guess[i]);
                check=1;
            }
           
        }
        if (check==0){
            printf("\033[0;31m");//red
            printf("%c", guess[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d | %c", word[0], guess[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to assign directly a value to word[0] but nothing works, at the end there's a comparison with guess[0] while printing word[0] in ASCII.
Any idea of what could be the problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Try to make the code smaller so it would be easier to find the problem. Delete everything that is not related to the problem (make sure to store a backup copy of your code somewhere). State clearly what it prints and what you want it to print. See also [mcve].

Comment: `scanf(" %8s", guess);` is incorrect: for `char guess[8]` you need `scanf(" %7s", guess);`

Comment: Or `scanf(" %8c", guess);` if you do not want a string terminator appended, but in that case you may want to clear the contents of `guess` first, in case the player inputs fewer than 8 characters.

Comment: Your description of the issue seems to be an *interpretation* of the problem.  What observable misbehavior do you actually *see* when you run the program?

Comment: If you truly want to test against an 8 character word, your character arrays need to be 9 characters in capacity as you need to accommodate the terminator character of the string ('\0').  You might want to delve into some "C" tutorials on character array usage.